# converting a node.js project into a wp plugin

Tags: plugin-development, javascript

What is the best way to take code written in node.js and convert it to a WP plug in without re-writing everything? Anyone have experience in doing this?

Comment: You're going to have to rewrite everything since Nodes APIs and syntax are not the same as PHP

Comment: You can the JavaScript from the node app for logic in the front end if possible https://medium.com/swlh/wordpress-create-react-app-integration-30b41657b79e

Comment: Thanks all for the help